# Операция :: c++

Tags: c++

Где и как можно использовать операцию :: ?

Comment: @Abyx это вопрос на экзамене, я не знаю как сделать его лаконичней

Comment: А что, в учебниках о таком уже не пишут? Вопрос не практический, а чисто теоритический, общий ответ на него  -это оператор смены области видимости. Например когда вы вне класса реализуете метод класса - перед именем метода ставится имя класса ::

Comment: @Mira я думала, что тег c++-faq для теоретических вопросов. В моём учебнике есть только 1 пример, а спрашивать будут всё

Comment: куда уж лаконичнее ))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`::` - это оператор, который используется для уточнения (квалификации) имен.

Бинарный оператор `::` уточняет область видимости в которой находится имя.
С левой стороны должна быть указана область видимости, с правой стороны - уточняемое имя.
В качестве области видимости может быть использовано пространство имен (namespace) или тип.

```
namespace NamespaceName {
  struct TypeName {
    typedef int NestedType;
  };
}
NamespaceName::TypeName a;  // имя TypeName находится в пространстве имен NamespaceName
NamespaceName::TypeName::NestedType b; // имя NestedType находится в типе NamespaceName::TypeName
decltype(a)::NestedType c; // имя NestedType находится в типе-результате decltype(a)
```

Унарный оператор `::` указывает что имя находится в глобальном пространстве имен.

```
int x;
int main() {
  int x;
  return ::x; // Глобальная переменная
}
```

Также как и для операторов `.` и `->`, после `::` может быть указано ключевое слово `template`, чтобы показать что далее в коде идет использование шаблона:

```
struct X {
  template<int>
  static void f();
};
template<class T>
void g() {
  T::f<1>(); // Ошибка: "<" означает оператор меньше
  T::template f<1>(); // ОК, используется шаблон f<1>
}
```